# Concurrency at the data row level

Tags: java, java-6

I have a `HashMap` and want to synchronize each row/entry separately in order to maximize concurrency, so in this way many threads can access the `HashMap` at the same time but no two threads or more can access the same row/entry at the same time.

I did the following in my code but I'm not sure if it's correct or not:

```
/* Lock/synchronize the data to this key, (skey is a key of type String) */
synchronized (aHashMap.get(skey)) {

    /* write the data (data is Integer) */
    aHashMap.put(skey, data);

}
```

Comment: I don't know that this will work, because access would be synchronized on the map level, not row level.  One thread enters the Object and no other thread can enter, right?

Comment: If the synchronize will lock the entire map because the reference is given between the two brackets in that case what are you saying is right. I want many threads to access the Hash Map at the same time but no two or more threads access the same row at the same time.

Comment: I'm interested in the answers given to this question, because I think my understanding of concurrency in Java is simplistic.  Intuitively, I don't see how you can lock on a per-row basis because our view of "rows" is an illusion.  Internally, there is just one storage area -- a hash area indexed by the hash of the key.  I could be working on two different "rows" but the hash could be colliding, and that's perfectly fine.  But it does mean that I can only synchronize on the map as a whole, not on the rows.  The "rows" are not really separate areas that can be locked individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appropriate solution depends very much on your particular problem. If all your threads can update any of the entries in the Map, then the first thing to try is [ConcurrentHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

In this case, the operation you described would be replaced with:

```
data = ... compute ...
aHashMap.replace(skey, data);
```

Using ConcurrentHashMap solves the data race but one problem remains. If another thread would update the same key at the same time, one of the computations would be lost. If you are ok with this, great. Otherwise, you can:

```
do {
  oldData = aHashMap.get(skey);
  data = ... compute (maybe based on oldData) ... 
  boolean success = aHashMap.replace(skey, oldData, data);
} while(!success);
```

In this case, replace will only succeed if the data hasn't changed (and the replace would be atomic). If if fails, you can put everything in a do while loop to try again, maybe based on the updated value.

Also, be careful not to have any side effects between the map get and replace. that computation should only create a brand new "data" object. If you update the "oldData" object or some other shared data you will get unexpected results.

If you do have side effects, one approach is to have make a key-level lock like this:

```
synchronized(skey) {
  data = ... compute ... 
  aHashMap.replace(skey, data);
}
```

Even in this case, ConcurrentHashMap is still needed. Also, this will not stop some other code from updating that key in the map. All code that updates the key would need to lock on it.

Also, this will not be thread-safe if you update oldData in "... compute ..." and the values are not unique within the map. If you do want to update oldData there, cover it with another synchronized.

If this does the trick and your content with the performance, look no further.

If the threads only update values, do not change the keys, then you might try converting your  pairs to objects and use something different than a Map. For example, you could split the set of  objects in several sets and then feed them to your threads. Or maybe use ParallelArray. But I might be digressing here... :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and yes all my threads can update any of the entries in the Map because each thread can hold any specific key and using it to update the data associate with that key, and I think your do{ }while(); solution is what I'm looking for, but I can't understand well how it will prevent two threads or more to access the same data row in the Map, please could you explain it more, thanks!

Comment: the idea is to allow multiple threads to access the same data. they speculatively compute the result and then try to update the Map. when they fail, they lose their computation and try again. but, in most cases, the chances of conflict are low so little computation is lost.

Comment: Also, be careful not to have any side effects between the map get and replace. that computation should only create a brand new "data" object. If you update the "oldData" object or some other shared data you will get unexpected results.

Comment: OK now I understood you but why not locking each row then any thread want to access a given row must acquire the row's lock?

Comment: first, if you consider the entries rows and they have int keys, then it might be a good idea to actually use arrays.

Comment: more to the point, as you asked about how to do this without locking on the entire map, I assumed performance is a concern. The algorithm above does not use locks at all and this makes it very fast. If you do need to update shared data, you can still use this approach and simply lock on some fine-grained object where you do the update. Still, in this case, remember that some computation is discarded. If you increment a count, for example, you would get unexpected results.

Comment: I'll add a version with key (row) level locks in case you need that.

Comment: OK thanks a lot for your help, I'm waiting your version with key (row) level locks because i would really like to know how to do it.

Comment: @mazen, ConcurrentHashMap doesn't need row level locks for thread safety. It removes the need for them as it improves performance.  Is there a specific reason you believe you have to have locking?

Comment: yes because I think that maybe one thread use the "get" to retrieve a value while another thread in another portion of the code use the "put" to write some new value (for the same row), so I will not guarantee the most recent result.

Comment: @PeterLawrey ConcurrentHashMap doesn't need locks for operations on it but it makes no guarantee regarding your other code. You can still get data races on values stored within the map or other atomicity violations. As I understand, mazen wants to make sure another thread doesn't mess up his computation between get and put. And locking on the key is a way to achieve that. mazen, this only works if your values are unique within the map. Otherwise you might want to sync on something else, maybe the value. Or both the value and the key.

Comment: @cos my values are not unique so how could I synchronize on the key or data or both? and if I do that I will no longer need to use ConcurrentHashMap instead I will use HashMap.

Comment: @mazen, If you want to perform a get, and replace, you need to use a loop as cos suggests. I have provided a simpler pattern which compiles, but it is the same idea.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey yes I will use it but what about if I have another "get" and "replace" in another portion of my code? because they could operate on the same entry??

Comment: @mazen, if they conflict, the loop will keep going around until they don't.

Answer (score 1):

You should really use the [ConcurrentHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) class available.

Your solution is buggy: As soon as another thread puts an item into the map which causes the hashmap to be expanded you may lose your update. Also it obviously depends on all users of the hashmap honoring the lock and if someone uses the object to lock something else, you'll run into a whole bag of problems.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the approach you have is that you are replacing the lcok object.  This means every thread which attempt to perform an update could be locking on a different object and this has the effect of doing nothing.

I would use ConcurrentHashMap as others have suggested.  You operation replaces the value so lock it, or any other object doesn't add any value here.

```
ConcurrentMap<Integer, Value> map = new ConcurrentMap<Integer, Value>();

// thread safe write of the data. No locks required.
map.put(skey, data);
```

---

EDIT:

if you have a get() and you want to update the a mutable value you can.

```
Value value = map.get(skey);
synchronized(value) {
    value.changeValue();
}
```

In this case there is no need to replace the same value. Value needs its own synchronization or Lock as its not thread safe.

---

If you want to "update" an immutable value you have to use a loop to keep trying the update.  This assumes there are no side effects of doing this.

```
while(true) {
   Value value = map.get(skey);
   Value value2 = compute(value);
   if(map.replace(skey, value, value2)) break;
}
```

This loop will keep iterating until it successfully replaces the value it expected to replace.  Given you will have much more keys (hundreds to millions) than cores (4-24) this loop will rarely loop more than once, but will try again when it has to.

Comment: But still i will get the most recent result?, because maybe one thread use the "get" to retrieve a value while another thread in another portion of the code use the "put" to write some new value (for the same row)

Comment: To get the most recent result, use `get()` The collection takes care of the thread safety.